# how to get json response without references with "ids"

Tags: java

so i have my project there is this part where there are 2 one to many relation ship to the same entity
what happens is that the response on the get request on postman come like this :
the one to many relationship is writen the same for both elements

```
{
   "elemnt1withonetomany": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "something",
        "last_name": "something",
        "email": "something"
    },
    "elemnt2withonetomany": {
        "@id": 4,
        "id": 4,
        "code": "details",
        "email": "details",
        "name": "details",
        "lastname": "details"
},
{
    "elemnt1withonetomany": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "something",
        "last_name": "something",
        "email": "something"
    },
 
    "element2withonetomany": 4,
```

}

so is there any way to make the get request gives the same form of information with elemnt2withonetomany

Answer (score 0):

i kinda found where it came from but then it's gonna need a lot of JsonBackReference and similar annotations
and yep it was from the @JsonIdentityInfo on top of the entities
kinda took me a while to find the source so i'm just gonna post what i found if someone needed it
so my new question is there a way to by pass it without deleting this one